# Hide div based on value of attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-masonry

I'm looking to change the class (hide) of certain div's dependent on their attribute values.
Here's my code, it might make a bit more sense once you've seen this:

```
jQuery('#menu1').click(function() {
      jQuery([.attr('imageref')]!=[.attr('menuref')]).removeClass('pics').addClass('.pics-hidden').removeClass('pics').fadeOut(200);
      jQuery('#projectimages').masonry('reload');
       });
```

So what I'm after is that if you click on `#menu1` it will remove `.pics` with the same `imageref` attribute as the `#menu1` atrribute `menuref`.

So clicking on `#menu1` which has `menuref` equal to 1, will hide the relevant `.pics` with an `imageref` also equal to 1.
Hopefully that makes sense, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you show the HTML structure in a fiddle?

Comment: What is your expectation of this syntax? `jQuery([.attr('imageref')]!=[.attr('menuref')])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the [*attribute-equals selector*](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), and concatenate into the selector the value of the `menuref` attribute.

```
jQuery('#menu1').click(function() {
      var menu = $(this).attr('menuref');
      jQuery(".pics[imageref='" + menu + "']").toggleClass('pics pics-hidden')
                                              .fadeOut(200);
      jQuery('#projectimages').masonry('reload');
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all your suggestions, @user1689607 answer worked great! One more small question regarding this code, as it does now hide all the images with the relevant 'imageref', is it also possible to hide all attributes BUT this one?

Comment: @user1374796: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to hide the `.pics`? Or the `menuX` items? Or maybe you mean to show all the `.pics` with the current `menuref`, and hide all the others?

Comment: Yes, I want to show all the .pics with the current menuref and hide all the others, if that's possible?

Comment: @user1374796: Put this in the code above in place of the line below the `var menu = ` line: `jQuery(".pics").hide().filter("[imageref='" + menu + "']")`

Comment: nearly there, but that seems to hide the whole class, as apposed to the ones without the relevant attribute?

Comment: @user1374796: Yes, it hides them all, but then filters the set down to the ones with the matching `menuref`, so you just need to add `.show()` to the end. I forgot to add it in my comment above.

Comment: that works great! The masonry doesn't reload after that though, is that at all possible?

Comment: *bump*...any reason the masonry isn't reloading at the end?

Comment: @user1374796: I don't know. Maybe you need the `.masonry("reload")` to be in a callback to the `.fadeOut()`? Like: `.fadeOut(200, function() { jQuery("#projectimages").masonry("reload"); });`

Comment: unfortunately not, I've tried that, it's still failing to reload masonry. I can't seem to figure out why at all?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know anything about masonry. Sorry. Make sure you're not seeing any errors in your browser's developer console.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the css selectors to make this.

ie:

```
jQuery('#menu1').click(function()
{
  jQuery('[imgeref="menuref"]').removeClass('pics').addClass('pics-hidden');
});
```

edit:

this will search all the elements wich his atribute 'imageref' is set to 'menuref' and then remove the class pics and add the class pics-hidden.
if it's only necesary to img tags. then you could change:

```
jQuery('[imgeref="menuref"]')
```

to

```
jQuery('img[imgeref="menuref"]')
```

Comment: A little more explanation would be nice. Also these selectors aren't specific to css3.

Answer (score 1):

You might use the jQuery filter function.

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

> Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

```
var menuref = ("#menu1").attr('menuref')
// Get all pics with an imageref attribute
jQuery(".pics[imageref]")
// Filter them
.filter(function(){
  return $(this).attr('imageref') != menuref; 
})
// Do what ever you want e.g. remove the pics class
.removeClass('pics')
```